# rsync to exclude everything except specific files

Tags: rsync

How to exclude all files except specific files with `rsync`?

I'm trying to only backup specific files with `rsync`, to exclude all files , except some specific files, namely the `.md` files, and solutions from all these pages didn't work for me:

- https://velenux.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/how-to-exclude-everything-except-a-specific-pattern-with-rsync/
- https://superuser.com/questions/1637543/how-to-specify-no-files-except-these-extensions-in-rsync
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1063730/rsync-exclude-all-files-in-dir-except-specific-files

```bash
$ rsync -vua --exclude="*" --include="*.md" ../log ./
sending incremental file list

sent 19 bytes  received 12 bytes  62.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ rsync -vua --include="*.md" --exclude="*" ../log ./
sending incremental file list

sent 19 bytes  received 12 bytes  62.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ du -sh ../log
1016M   ../log

$ apt-cache policy rsync
rsync:
  Installed: 3.2.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
  Candidate: 3.2.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 500
        500 http://ca-toronto-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.3-8ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ca-toronto-1-ad-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to copy the files from anywhere below `../log`.

If a name matches an `--include` or `--exclude` pattern, the remaining patterns on the command line will not be used ("first match wins").  You will never recurse if you don't match `*/` with an `--include` pattern.

Taking these things into consideration, match `*.md` and `*/` with `--include` before matching `*` with `--exclude`:

```bash
rsync --archive --update --verbose --include='*.md' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ../log .
```

Add `-m` or `--prune-empty-dirs` if you wish to avoid creating empty directories.

Answer (score 3):

Options apply from left to right, so you need to include items before you exclude the rest

```
rsync -av --include '*.md' --include '*/' --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs src/ dst/
```

Here, we include the files you want, include subdirectories (so we can descend into them looking for matches), but exclude everything else. Directories that would end up being empty are skipped too.